# Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Use Cauchy's Theorem to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi ix \xi} dx = e^{-\pi \xi^2}$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

It wants us to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi ix \xi} dx = e^{-\pi \xi^2}$ by integrating $f(z) = e^{-\pi z^2}$ over the rectangle with vertices $\pm n, \pm n + i \xi$ and taking the limit $n \to \infty$. I have tried to do this using Cauchy's Integral Formula, but it ends up with a nasty integral that results in $\text{erf}(z)$, which I know for a fact we cannot use. Any help on how to start with this problem? I have seen similar questions but none that asked to find it by integrating over this $2n \times i \xi$ rectangle.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Estimate the integral over $\left[\pm m,\pm n+i\xi\right]$, then you will find that they vanish as $n\to \infty$. Then the integral over $\left[-n+i\xi,n+i\xi\right]$ agree with that over $\left[-n,n\right]$ as $n\to \infty$. Rewrite the former as an integral over $\left[-n,n\right]$.

Comment: Sorry, where did you get the interval $[\pm m, \pm n + i \xi]$? Also, what would the second integrals that you're discussing look like? I am not really that familiar with Cauchy's Integral Theorem..

Comment: @robertlewison Sorry, that's $\left[\pm n,\pm n+i\xi\right]$.

Comment: @robertlewison Are you allowed to know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}dx=1$?

Comment: @operatorerror no, we’re not allowed to use that fact. That’s what made it particularly difficult for me

Comment: @robertlewison then I don't think it is possible with this method, as the answers below suggest.

Answer (score 2):

We first estimate the integral of $e^{-\pi z^2}$ over $\left[\pm n,\pm n+i\xi\right]$. Note that for $z=\pm n+ic$ on the segment, we have
$$\left | e^ {z^2} \right |  =e^{c^2-\pi n^2 }\leqslant e^{\xi^2-\pi n^2}, $$
therefore
$$\left | \int_{\pm n}^{\pm n+i\xi } e^{-\pi z^2}\mathrm d z \right | \leqslant \left | \xi  \right |e^{\xi^2-\pi n^2}\to 0. $$
Now fix $n$, it is easy to see that the integrand is analytic.Recall that
$$\text{The Rectangle}=\left [ -n,n \right ] \cup \left [ -n+i\xi,n +i\xi \right ] \cup \left [ n,n+i\xi  \right ] \cup \left [ -n,-n+i\xi  \right ] $$
and the whole integral over the rectangle is $0$. Take $n\to \infty$ and we see that
$$\int_{-\infty+i\xi }^{\infty+i\xi} e^{-\pi z^2}\mathrm d z=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-\pi z^2}\mathrm d z.$$
Therefore we have
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-\pi \left ( z+i\xi \right ) ^2}\mathrm d z=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-\pi z^2}\mathrm d z=1.$$
Take the $e^{\pi\xi^2}$ out from the left hand side and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy's theorem, we have;
$$\oint f(z)dz=\oint e^{-\pi z^2}dz=0$$

$$\therefore\int_{-n}^{n}e^{-\pi z^2}dz+\int_{n}^{n+i\zeta}e^{-\pi z^2}dz+\int_{n+i\zeta}^{-n+i\zeta}e^{-\pi z^2}dz+\int_{-n+i\zeta}^{-n}e^{-\pi z^2}dz=0$$

In the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ we will have;

$$0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi z^2}dz+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{n+i\zeta}^{-n+i\zeta}e^{-\pi z^2}dz$$

Applying the substitution $z=m+i\zeta$ yields;

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi z^2}dz=-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{n}^{-n}e^{-\pi (m+i\zeta)^2}dm=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi (m+i\zeta)^2}dm$$

Utilizing the fact that $\small\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}dx=1$ then gives us;

$$1=e^{\pi\zeta^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi m^2}e^{-2\pi i m \zeta}dm$$

Leaving us with the final identity;

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi m^2}e^{-2\pi i m \zeta}dm=e^{-\pi\zeta^2}$$

as expected.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the step where you simplified $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(m-i\xi)^2} \, dm$, how does that simplify to leave us with the $-2\pi im\xi$ term in the next step? Wouldn't that term be positive?
$$-\pi(m-i\xi)^2 \Rightarrow -\pi(m^2 - \xi^2 - 2mi\xi) \Rightarrow -\pi m^2 + \pi \xi^2 + 2\pi mi \xi$$

Comment: @robertlewison You are correct...that was a mistake. I edited my answer accordingly.